# If Unity is not in the GAC, how does VS know to show it in Add References?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reference, gac, add-references-dialog

I'm trying to index the GAC and use the `ResolveAssemblyReferences` target. However, some assemblies (such as Unity application block) seem to be missing from the GAC and yet VS happily shows them in the Add Reference dialog. My question: how can this be? I always thought that only GAC-registered assemblies appear there. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm assuming Unity Application Block (the IoC Container)

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about Unity application block :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the registry setting ckramer mentioned, there is also `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx`.

Tip: if you download the [VS 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension, the updated "Add Reference" dialog clearly distinguishes between Framework assemblies and Framework Extension assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a registry setting which allows you to add directories to the list of locations where Visual Studio will search for assemblies to display in the "Add References" dialog.

[Here](http://www.csharp411.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-visual-studio-add-reference-dialog/) is a quick overview of where it is and how to add your own paths to it.